# How to achieve Android Photos app UI

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, imageview, photos

I'm writing an app just exactly like the Google's Photos app for academic purpose. So I'm struggling with building this activity. Sorry for the app language.

[image]

Basically what I wan't is to query all image in device and put them nicely on UI, group them into days (months, years, currently in pic is grouping into days): a line of text writes date, then followed by picture(s) in that day, and so on.

**For example:**

1. Date 29/4 I have one picture
2. Date 28/4 I have 5 pictures and so on.

I did successfully query all image using ContentResolver but I'm struggling with the UI, I can't put them nicely like the Photos app. I use an GridView contains multiple ImageView and TextView, here is what I've done:

[image]

Can't anybody help me how to accomplish the Photos app UI, I'm still new to Android? And what it's composed of? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Please describe what UI feature you are trying to implement EXACTLY as all you've done is describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question, do you see it any better?

Comment: It may help to read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: I am interested in the same thing, and haven't found anything.  Did you ever figure this out?